# Dual-boot windows 10/Arch linux, able to boot into Linux, but windows blue screens

Tags: windows, boot, grub, arch-linux, dualboot

I'm having this dual-boot problem, where booting from grub to Arch Linux is not a problem, however booting into windows leaves a blue-screen.

[This is the blue screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMygK.jpg)

**In the grub menu:**

- Able to boot into Arch linux, and that goes fine.
- OS-Prober recognises and detects the windows operating system, in the grub menu at boot

**NOTE:** If I access the BIOS on my machine, I can still boot into windows if I change the boot-priority.

I've gone through many articles and many forums, so this is the last attempt, I hope you can help.

**Disclaimer**: I'm not an experienced user with the Arch-Linux operating system. I have not followed the Arch-Linux-Wiki for the installation process, I've instead followed a Youtube video, from a channel that has helped me before, so skipping ahead in the video might give you some useful information on what the problem might be.
**This is the youtube video**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGhifbn6088

Comment: If it boot directly but not via Grub then you need to update Grub. First make sure that Fast Startup in Windows is disabled, a must when dual-booting. Then https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111889/how-do-i-update-grub-in-arch-linux

Comment: It only boots directly if I switch the Windows partition to be first in the boot priority, otherwise it boots into grub and I can choose Both Arch and windows from there. Updated grub nonetheless and fast startup is disabled.